# Batch add users to BIM360

Tags: python, forge, autodesk-bim360

I used Forge API to post projects in BI360, now I am trying to add few users using the data frame of the projects created. According to the Forge Documentation you can post users to one project, looking for  an advise how to post users to several projects

TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked, and all endpoints take only one project id, so you have to loop through multiple projects and add the user(s) to all projects, currently not possible in one call.